# How to enable SSH in Deeplens camera after the initial registration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-deeplens

I have registered my Amazon Deeplens camera in the AWS console and selected to disable SSH and automatic updates. Then I found that in order to update it manually it's necessary to login into the shell of the the camera (Ubuntu) so, for convenience, I want to enable back SSH.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that you will have to access the camera using a monitor, mouse and keyboard. then login into Ubuntu using the same credentials as the user you selected for the camera configuration, open a shell and login and verify ssh is running:

```
> service ssh status
```

If it is enabled then you just need to enable the rules to connect to port 22:

```
> sudo ufw allow ssh
```

If it's not then you need to enable and start ssh first:

```
> sudo systemctl start ssh
> sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

Then you can ssh into the cam with:

```
> ssh aws_cam@YOUR_CAM_IP_ADDRESS
```

and optionally update awscam manually (if this is what you want):

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install awscam
> sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the device you can connect to it's web administrative interface and enable/disable SSH. See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deeplens/latest/dg/deeplens-getting-started-set-up.html